# Get filename mapped into memory by the address it's mapped to

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, memory

assuming there's the following code -

```
HANDLE h = CreateFile(L"some_dll.dll", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
HANDLE map = CreateFileMapping(h, NULL, PAGE_READONLY | SEC_IMAGE, 0, 0, NULL);
LPVOID res = MapViewOfFileEx(map, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Is it possible to extract 'some_dll', given the address it's mapped to, using c++ ?

When trying to debug this executable using windbg, it seems that it doesn't extract the module well too

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly what [GetMappedFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683195(v=vs.85).aspx) is for:

> Checks whether the specified address is within a memory-mapped file in the address space of the specified process. If so, the function returns the name of the memory-mapped file.

PS: there's no reason for `windbg` to show the name of a memory mapped file that isn't a loaded module, even if the file happens to be a DLL.

Comment: The file mapping (i.e. Section object) is mapped as `SEC_IMAGE`, for which the Memory Manager maps the individual sections as specified in the PE/COFF image header. So WinDbg does display the `Name` from the mapped image's `IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY`, which IIRC is gets overridden by whatever name is in the loader's module table if it was actually loaded as a module. VC++ sets this export directory `Name` field when it builds a DLL. It seems the tool used to build this DLL left it blank.